"Error:1004 Application-defined or object-defined error" while trying to modify a cell
I am running the following code in excel:
Debug.Print wb.Name
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name
ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value = "Hello"

I am getting the following output:
lin_reg.xlsm
Data_collection
Error number: 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

The line which is modifying the value throws error. I don't seem to understand what this causing this. Please help.
I tried selecting all cells and unlocking them. It did not help.

Your code as posted cannot run. Certain modifications to enable it to run do not produce the error you show. Please edit your question to provide sufficient information so your problem can be reproduced by others.

It doesn't matter if the cells are locked or unlocked unless the worksheet is protected. If this is the case, unprotect it, write to it, and protect it again. If not, share the rest of the code.

Solved it. Actually I was modifying cell value from a function. Changed it to sub and it worked!
